# Different value in src="" each time the element is clicked, receiving image links from an API

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

**Full code:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getFact } from "./api/fact";
import { getKittenPictures } from "./api/kittenPictures";
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@mui/material/CardMedia';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { CardActionArea } from '@mui/material';

function App() {

  const [fact, setFact] = useState([]);
  const [newFact, setNewFact] = useState(0);
  const [kittenPicture, setKittenPicture] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getFact().then((data) => setFact(data.fact));
  }, [newFact]);

  kittenPicture.map((pic) => (
    console.log(pic.largeImageURL)
    /* 
      RESULT:

      https://pixabay.com/get/gaf757505d28827f92bd5ae929e21a4d10682d9d953a25eba59be43f7ae664a3b608fcd78540558511718584c6d3eb8d59b78dcb9ecc95ee4f6c69e687b5402e2_1280.jpg
      https://pixabay.com/get/g0b085f788b1f55a460e2a7595c23ce7b710cc8447fb9ab773ad53ecb779b067d27919f057826d9a0efb0b7e8d3a12963f95c7619c5c2072e3da7bc3380936df9_1280.jpg
      https://pixabay.com/get/g117582a7914c3e2bcb5dd4d6a7feaffc4b09ed2ebb14669269ad181bf0c672bd4adb1fac6c6baefa5bf40e2fd7e7c232e52222118019e315ac9e5704398f61c8_1280.jpg
      ...
    */
  ));

  useEffect(() => {
    getKittenPictures().then((data) => setKittenPicture(data.hits));
  }, [newFact]);

  const onNewFactHandler = () => {
    setNewFact(newFact + 1);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <Card md={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
          <CardActionArea onClick={onNewFactHandler}>
            <CardMedia
              component="img"
              src=""
              alt="Cute kitten"
            />
            <CardContent>
              <Typography gutterBottom variant="h4" component="div">Random cat fact</Typography>
              <Typography variant="body1" color="black">{fact}</Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </CardActionArea>
        </Card>
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**My goal:** Set a link in my image attribute `src=""`, received from a response from the image API

**Current situation:**

- The API returns the correct values.
- Using a `console.log` I can print all the image links that I can insert into `src=""` via my `kittenPicture` state, using `map()`, like this:

```
kittenPicture.map((pic) => (
    console.log(pic.largeImageURL)
));
```

- The results I receive are as shown in the comment, but would be as follows:

```
https://pixabay.com/get/gaf757505d28827f92bd5ae929e21a4d10682d9d953a25eba59be43f7ae664a3b608fcd78540558511718584c6d3eb8d59b78dcb9ecc95ee4f6c69e687b5402e2_1280.jpg
https://pixabay.com/get/g0b085f788b1f55a460e2a7595c23ce7b710cc8447fb9ab773ad53ecb779b067d27919f057826d9a0efb0b7e8d3a12963f95c7619c5c2072e3da7bc3380936df9_1280.jpg
https://pixabay.com/get/g117582a7914c3e2bcb5dd4d6a7feaffc4b09ed2ebb14669269ad181bf0c672bd4adb1fac6c6baefa5bf40e2fd7e7c232e52222118019e315ac9e5704398f61c8_1280.jpg
...
```

**The main problem:** I don't have idea about how to get one of those links and put it in  this `src=""`:

```
<CardMedia
     component="img"
     src=""
     alt="Cute kitten"
/>
```

**What I have tried:**

- Map all the links inside the `<CardMedia>` component, although I know it is not correct, as it will print all the images:

```
<CardActionArea onClick={onNewFactHandler}>
  {kittenPicture.map((pic) => (
    <CardMedia
      component="img"
      src={pic.largeImageURL}
      alt="Cute kitten"
    />
  ))}
  <CardContent>
    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h4" component="div">Random cat fact</Typography>
    <Typography variant="body1" color="black">{fact}</Typography>
  </CardContent>
</CardActionArea>
```

- Set the first image always:

```
<CardMedia
  component="img"
  src={kittenPicture[0].largeImageURL}
  alt="Cute kitten"
/>
```

This works, but only in the first render. If for example I reload the page, I get the next error:

> Uncaught TypeError: kittenPicture[0] is undefined

(I believe this is because fetch has not yet retrieved the data)

At this point, I don't know how to get what I want. Any ideas?

Comment: `kittenPicture` is at the first render empty. so index `0` doesnt exists. just wrap it with `kittenPicture.length ? (<CardMedia.... />) ? : null`

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your `kittenPicture.map(...` code inside of the `useEffect` after you pull the URLs. Right now, it runs before the `useEffect` has finished, so the `kittenPicture` array doesn't exist yet.

Then, similar to what @Sysix said, Add a conditional before rendering the cards so that if `kittenPicture` is undefined, you don't get an error!